# iOS 10 UNNotificationAction, can move from background to foreground mode?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios10

UINotificationAction is defined as below

```
let customAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "customCategory.Action", title: "Do something", options: [])
```

On click, this will make a web service request to fetch data using `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` method as below

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let actionIdentifier = response.actionIdentifier
    switch actionIdentifier {
    case customCategory.Action:
        if authTokenNotExpired {
            // Make service call
        } else {
            // Show login screen (In foreground)
        }

    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

But the application has login and when auth token expires, the web service request fails.

As per requirement, in this failure scenario, the login screen should be displayed.

Is it possible to move the application from background mode to foreground in order to display login screen?

Comment: you cannot make app come to foreground by iteself. Though you can chaneg the root controller, and show login screen whenever you need!

Comment: Show login screen, will happen only when application again launched by user click right?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is different from what you want.. In order to have like this..
1 solution is to do like this in appdelegate:

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(triggerGetNewToken(note:)), name: .isNeedNewToken, object: nil)
  }

@objc func triggerGetNewToken(note:NSNotification){
    debugLog(logMessage: "GETTING NEW TOKENS NOW IN APPDELEGATE!")
    api_token.param(serverKey: appkey)
}
```